# When debugging JavaScript using the Chrome developer tools, what information can I use to diagnose a site crash?

Tags: javascript, debugging

What information can I take from the following debug pause? I don't see any information that I can use to identify the problem :s

UPDATE:
[image]
console is empty

Comment: also, go to the console and tell us the error.

Comment: I can't see where comes the error :s

Answer (score 3):

The code you show is minified, that's why it's only one line and not readable nor directly debbugable.

But you have a small button <kbd>**{ }**</kbd> at the bottom left of the screen you show (the fifth from the left), it lets you beautify the code. Click on it.

You can put breakpoints in this beautified code in a much precise way.

Comment: well then.  you have no idea how much easier you just made my life.

Comment: @RussellUhl glad to know that my answer wasn't useless :)

Comment: I click the button {} and it turns blue but the code still the same :s

Answer (score 0):

When you are debugging your own website, you should load the uncompressed version of jQuery and any other libraries you need to debug. If you're loading jQuery from the Google or jQuery CDNs, simply change `jquery.min.js` to `jquery.js`.

If you're serving jQuery from your own server, always check in both the compressed and uncompressed versions into your source tree. This applies to other libraries too. You don't want to have nothing but the compressed code available.

By using the original uncompressed source, you will have the formatted code with all its comments and the original variable names.

When you don't have access to the original code or just need to take a quick look at something, dystroy's tip about using the built-in DevTools beautifier is an excellent one. It cleans up the formatting nicely, you just don't get the comments or original variable names.